# no syntax highlighting for Ruby Gemfile in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, syntax-highlighting

I created a new app in Ruby on Rails and opened up Notepad++. It seems that most of the files are syntax highlighted for Ruby on Rails to make for easier development.

One problem, though is the Gemfile, which is not given a Ruby File extension:

`Gemfile` not `Gemfile.rb`.

Is there anyway to apply Ruby syntax highlighting to the Gemfile without changing the extension?

Comment: **Reviewers:** This question is about an editor and qualifies as a "tool used primarily for programming." It should not be closed as off-topic/general computing software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select menu **Language -> R -> Ruby** and this will apply coloring to the document. Unfortunately you'll have to repeat this every time you open the file.